# do not order x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I read data from a file using read.table as `i<- read.table("path", header=T,sep="\t",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`
`x <- i$Window`. The values of x are in the order +100, -200, +300, -400 etc I donot want ggplot to re-order it and want to reatin the same order s read from file. I tried many things like `i$Window <- factor(i$Window, levels=c("+100","-200","+300","-400"), order =FALSE)`. But everything orders the x-axis. I saw many similar question here, but nothing helped. Could you please suggest something, especially without hard coding the x-axis values would be better, as the number and value of elements are variable.

Comment: Can you add the result of running `dput(your_data)` to your question? And how are you plotting exactly? In other words, please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: But as a general solution not depending on hard-coding, you can use `mydata$x_ordered_from_file <- factor(mydata$x, levels=unique(mydata$x))`

Comment: What are you plotting exactly?? If lines, the use `geom_path(...)` not `geom_line(...)`. The latter will reorder the points.

Answer (score 0):

i$Window2 <- factor(i$Window, as.character(i$Window)) and then plotting with i $Window2 as x-axis, solved the problem :)